# ReSharper wont function properly in Visual Studio 2012 running on Windows 8

Tags: .net, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, resharper-7.0

I installed Visual Studio 8 on Windows 8 with Resharper 7.0.1, and I have some problems getting Resharper to function properly. It seems most of ReSharper does not work, but here is some of the strange behaviour I have noticed:

- Clicking `Ctrl-Shift+T` opens up the select file or folder dialog, but when I select a file from here and click enter the dialog closes, but the file is not opened up
- `Ctrl+R+R` (rename) gives the message that the key is bound to Resharper Rename, but that it is not currently available, even when the cursor is inside a variable in a standard .cs file, and the program is not debugging.
- Alt+Enter does nothing, so the context menu does not pop up at all anywhere.

Does anyone know if ReSharper is not supposed to work under Win 8, or is it something that is messed up on my machine? In that case what?

**EDIT**

Notices that code analysis isn't working either. So that "bar" on the right hand side of the code windows that displays the green. yellow and red lines to indicate problems is not there.

Comment: I'm using ReSharper 7 in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 without any problems.

Comment: I'm a new user to ReSharper, so shortcuts you mention are new to me. I use F2 for Rename, but get same behavior as you for Ctrl+R+R. Ctrl+Shift+T takes me to source of method return type. This is on Windows 7, VS 2010. Maybe mappings changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a reinstall of Resharper did the trick. I removed Reshaper now, and reinstalled it and now it seems like everything is working fine.

Don't know what went wrong the first time, but now it's back to normal.

Comment: This answer worked for me. I think I had VS (2013) running when I ran the install the first time. That might have messed it up.

Answer (score 23):

You probably are running without any keyboard scheme. You can reset it to something more useful:

1. Go to the following part of the settings: **ReSharper** => **Options** => **Environment** => **Keyboard & Menus**
2. Select **Visual Studio**
3. Press **Apply Scheme**

Next time you press a keybinding that is already in use by Visual Studio you will get the chance to switch the the ReSharper keybinding (or keep the original Visual Studio keybinding).

Comment: Already tried this. It's set to Visual Studio. If I reset it, and try a command (for example Shift+Ctrl+T) i get a popup of which shortcut to use. Here i selected ReSharper, and checked the do this for all shortcuts checkbox, but the problem remains.

Comment: You may need to reset your visual studio keyboard settings too.  [This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/08/05/keyboard-shortcuts-reset-all-your-shortcuts-vstiptool0064.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+zainnab+(Visual+Studio+Tips+and+Tricks)) may help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had a similar problem.
I was missing some “Coding Assistance Context Actions”
See http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Context_Actions.html
I could solve my problem by deleting the Annotaions.cs in my Properties folder ( which is auto generated by Resharper). After Resharper created a new Annotaions.cs the missing options missing were available again.